# file_get_html failed to open stream: Connection refused in

Tags: php, function, file-get-contents, connection-refused, failed-to-connect

I got this function to get some info from a external URL.
Problems is, if the website got robots no-index this function crashes which crashes the foreach loop afterwards.

**Error msg:**

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://webontwerp-arnhem.nl/contact): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/vhosts/free-sitemap-generator.com/httpdocs/includes/cra/simple_html_dom.php on line 79
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/free-sitemap-generator.com/httpdocs/includes/cra/xml-functions.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/free-sitemap-generator.com/httpdocs/crawler.php(44): crawl_site('http://webontwe...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/free-sitemap-generator.com/httpdocs/includes/cra/xml-functions.php on line 60

**Function:**

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);

    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

**Calling the function with loop:**

```
function crawl_site($u) {
    $urlList = array();
    global $crawled_urls, $found_urls;
    $uen = urlencode($u);
    if ((array_key_exists($uen, $crawled_urls) == 0 || $crawled_urls[$uen] < date("YmdHis", strtotime('-25 seconds', time())))) {
        $html = file_get_html($u);

        $crawled_urls[$uen] = date("YmdHis");
        foreach($html -> find("a")as $li) {
            $url = perfect_url($li -> href, $u);
            $enurl = urlencode($url);
            $str = basename($url);
            $dirn = dirname($url);
            if ($url != '' && substr($url, 0, 4) != "mail" && substr($url, 0, 3) != "tel" && substr($url, 0, 5) != "phone" && substr($url, 0, 5) != "skype" && substr($url, 0, 4) != "java" && array_key_exists($enurl, $found_urls) == 0) {
                $found_urls[$enurl] = 1;
                $pos = strpos($str[0], '#');
                $ext = strpos($url, $u);
                if ($ext != = false && $pos == = false) {
                    echo "<li><div class='url-row'>$dirn/<span class='strong'>$str</span></div></li>";

                    array_push($urlList, $url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the error is at `$html->find("a")` , have an "if" check before that line: `if($html){ `.... and after that try to perform the "foreach"

Comment: Yes I've tryed but for example: If site.com/page_1 has no robot meta tag but if site.com/page_2 does have robots noindex. It wont loop site.com/page_1. Thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL in place of file_get_contents()

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://webontwerp-arnhem.nl/contact';         
    $ch = curl_init();        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    $contents = curl_exec ($ch);        
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I tryd, it returns empty.

Comment: Maybe try to change the User-Agent